# Problem with loading required library modules when loading an app module within a new ModuleLayer

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I'm trying to create a new layer (other than the boot layer) and load a Java module (ModuleA) from a specific directory path in it. The below code can successfully locate and load ModuleA itself, but it can't resolve the library modules that ModuleA requires:

```
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(Paths.get(modulePath));
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of(moduleName));

ClassLoader scl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer.Controller newLayer = ModuleLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, List.of(parent), scl);
```

I get the following exception from the `resolve` method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module <library module> not found, required by <ModuleA>
```

Do you know how I could resolve all required modules (including library modules) along with ModuleA?

Comment: More information would be useful. Where are the library modules located? What is the result of `Paths.get(modulePath)` (directory or file)?

Comment: @Slaw The libraries could be any kind of libraries (included in pom.xml by maven, or in the project file, ...). The output of `Paths.get(...)` is an object of java.nio.file.Paths which is used as an input to `ModuleFinder.of()`.

Comment: I was wondering if it was a directory or a file. The library modules, if not in a parent `ModuleLayer`, need to be visible to the `ModuleFinder` you're creating; if the `Path` is a directory that contains those libraries then that would be so.

Comment: @Slaw yes, I know that if I manually give the path of all libraries to the `ModuleFinder`, it could load them. My question is that is there a way to programmatically find and add all libraries (or their paths) to be provided to `ModuleFinder`? (Maybe using the classpath of the application whose modules we want to load)

Comment: That sounds like configuration which should be given to the code responsible for loading the new modules. You could put this information in a properties file, system property, user preferences, a database, or it could be resolved based on where you put your plugins. However, I believe using the classpath would be a bad idea (at least, it wouldn't be my first choice).